# How to load modules in Angular Electron?

Tags: angularjs, module, dependencies, electron, ng-animate

I have a functioning angular electron application which was made using this boilerplate code:
https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron

I am trying to add the ngSanitize module (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) to my application and I'm stuck at "loading the module in your application by adding it as a dependent module":

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

How can I do this in an angular electron application with the current file setup? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Like you can read on electron's website it uses Angular v2+ (currently 6.1.2). And you are trying write in AngularJS.
For the beginning here is something about modules: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules but I would suggest you get familiar with whole tutorial and new version of Angular